# SET FMTONLY OFF effects on stored procedures with dynamic query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, telerik, telerik-reporting

I use Telerik Report designer R1 2017, and use a stored procedure with dynamic query as data source. It appears the schema cannot be obtained from the dynamic query. I Googled and found out that it's not possible without adding the following lines in the beginning of the stored procedure

```
IF 1 = 0 BEGIN
 SET FMTONLY OFF
END
```

But I have really slow execution in this way! I'm not very familiar with store procedure execution process. I want to know What negative effects can it (`SET FMTONLY OFF`) have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `SQL Server 2012+` you could use `WITH RESULT SETS` to define resultset:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.mysp_test
AS
BEGIN

   DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT id, b FROM dbo.tab  ' + 'WHERE 1=1';

   EXEC sp_executesql @sql

END
GO

SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set (
  'EXEC dbo.mysp_test'
  ,NULL
  ,NULL
);
```

> The metadata could not be determined because statement 'EXEC sp_executesql @sql' in procedure 'mysp_test'  contains dynamic SQL.

Using `WITH RESULT SETS`:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.mysp_test
AS
BEGIN

   DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT id, b FROM dbo.tab  ' + 'WHERE 1=1';

   EXEC sp_executesql @sql
   WITH RESULT SETS(  
        (id INT NOT NULL,
         b CHAR(1)
        )  
    ); 
END
GO

SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set (
  'EXEC dbo.mysp_test'
  ,NULL
  ,NULL
);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_next&fiddle=521d807f00da576f0f99b6f930c80b3c)**

Comment: Good solution, Thank you. But as I mentioned in question, I couldn't understand disadvantages of SET FMTONLY OFF. And also now, I don't know why using WITH RESULT SETS is preferred.

Comment: @Elnaz [`SET FMTONLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-fmtonly-transact-sql) is deprecated feature